# How To Hide List Column in SharePoint 2010

Tags: site-column, hide-elements

[image]

how can i hide this column as hidden option is greyed out(not available).

Comment: check your permissios

Comment: You want to hide from list view or form?

Comment: yes from listform webpart which is using this list

Answer (score 2):

To hide any list column follow these steps:

**1.** Go to *List Settings* > *Advanced Settings*

**2.** Select option '*Yes*' for *Allow management of content types?*

[image]

**3.** Now, in *List Settings*, go to '*Item*' content type in *Content Types* section.

[image]

**4.** In *Columns* section click on the column you want to make hidden.

**5.** In *Column Settings* > Select *Hidden* option > OK

[image]

**EDIT:**

To hide Calculated column follow this: [Hide Calculated Column in SharePoint 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/157777/hide-calculated-column-in-sharepoint-2013)

Comment: Yes i tried exactly this but hidden option is coming unavailable for me, my column is calculated type column.

Comment: Follow updated answer, where you can hide calculated column by SPD.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open SharePoint Designer.
2. Open the website that contains your list with the calculated column.
3. Click on "Lists and Libraries" in the left column (under Site Objects).
4. On the right, click on the list that contains your calculated column.
   Under "Content Types", click on the content type where you want to hide the calculated column
5. In the content type screen, click "Edit content type columns"
6. In the column "Property", try clicking a few times on the "Optional" value until it changes into a dropdown list.
7. Select "Hidden" from the dropdown list and click on push changes to sites and lists on ribbon.
8. Finally Save your changes.

Reference: [Hide Calculated Column in SharePoint 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/157777/hide-calculated-column-in-sharepoint-2013)

Comment: With screenshots: http://viewmaster365.com/365coach/#/Blog_hidecolumn

Answer (score 0):

It's gray out because you're using a calculated column which already doesn't show on the New and Edit Form. the display from will show the field so you should create a new display form and remove the fields from it.

Hope this is helpful,

Tarik Laabar